# How to fix C drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, chkdsk

I dismounted my C drive to wipe free space & run `chkdsk` utility. When at 25% through the `chkdsk` I decided to cancel and after that restarted the laptop. It logged in but I was seeing errors like `can't load something on c:/$drive`.

I was receiving that message from many programs I was trying to run. It also said it couldn't load Windows log on; I was already logged in? So I decided to restart again then this is where I was no longer able to access my C drive. It says `loading windows`, but then the screen turns blue and the computer restarts. I can't access system restore nor do I have the installation CD.

Comment: First if check disk deleted files its already to late to recover them, that indicates the file system had significant problems, because stopping a check disk on a healthy drive wouldn't have resulted in what happen.  **You require a system disk to fix this problem**

Comment: is it possible that the drive is not mounted as C?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You should probably try restarting in Safe Mode. Right after BIOS loads keep pressing F8 to see safe mode option. In that screen, select Safe Mode and see if it gives any error.

And if it doesn't work then you should try getting a installation from somewhere, internet or a friend. After getting a installation disk perform the following steps.

Start your Windows however it is. Insert Windows installation of your installed version, like if you've installed Windows 7 Professional then insert Windows 7 Professional installation disk.

Then open Command Prompt as Administrator. Type the command

```
sfc /scannow
```

SFC is actually System File Checker. It will detect and fix any corrupted file that your Windows has.

Comment: It states in the OP he does not have the installation CD "nor do I have the installation CD".

Comment: thanks, all. I tried safe mode but the blue screen appears there too.  how can the drive be mounted as anything other than c? how can that happen?